# Update to 3.9.16 failing before it starts

Tags: joomla3.0

I'm running Joomla 3.9.15. I'm trying to update to 3.9.16. PHP is 7.3.15.

I have tried updating from the home page and under components. I have also tried to update by uploading the patch file. In either case, Joomla reports a 500 error before even starting.

The akeeba backup before update is enabled but I disabled it and get the same 500 error.

I also used Akeeba tools to set fix permissions that did not help either.

I looked at the logs but could not find anything there that would help. I also enabled debug but nothing was reported there either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Carter

Comment: To anyone who looked at this post, thank you. I kept trying things until I found a solution. I solved it by increasing the size of the permissible upload file size in php. Thanks again.

Comment: Questions should not be resolved by comments.  Please post an answer, then accept your answer when the system allows it.